# Эмулировать поведение js в android webview как в браузере

Tags: javascript, android, webview, браузер

Открываю страницу в WebView, и информация выводится неверно, а точнее просто не так, как, например, в браузере на этом же устройстве (на iPhone webview и в других браузерах всё в порядке).

Возможно ли применить к android webview какие-нибудь настройки, которые изменят работу js? Пробовал setWebChromeClient, setWebViewClient, getSettings().setUserAgentString - никакого влияния на внешний вид страницы. Важно, что проблема возникает на устройствах с версией android выше чем 4.1

UPD: getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) используется. Причём тот самый модуль, который для меня важен, вообще не выводится без вызова у webview этой функции.

[image: native browser]
[image: webview]

Comment: `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` делали?

Comment: @metalurgus, да, сделано. Глупо было с моей стороны это не уточнить. Добавил в UPD.